# How do you label bands in a GDAL VRT so that their label is recognised in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal

I'm writing a VRT using GDAL's Python bindings, and I want the band name to be recognised in QGIS.

Currently the bands are labelled as `band 1` and `band 2` and so on, but I'd like them to be `Red`, `Green` and so on.

I'm writing the VRT like this:

```py
options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(separate=True)
my_vrt = gdal.BuildVRT(vrt_name, [str(t) for t in tifs], options=options)
del my_vrt
```

[image: QGIS band dialog]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. I was originally placing the XML tag in the wrong spot.

Code below adds the colour interpretation tag in the right place, and QGIS recognises it!

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(vrt_name)
root = tree.getroot()
for band in root.iter("VRTRasterBand"):
    source = band.find("ComplexSource")
    file_name = source.find("SourceFilename").text

    # Colour interpretation is good
    colour_interp = ET.SubElement(band, "ColorInterp")
    colour = file_name.split("_")[-1].split(".")[0]
    colour_interp.text = colour

    # Description appears more useful though
    description = ET.SubElement(band, "Description")
    description.text = colour

# Update the file on disk
tree.write(vrt_name)
```

Note that "Description" ends up in the lowercase field and "ColourInterp" ends up in brackets

[image: description and colour interpretation tags]