# Setting default raster band colour interpretation for QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, multi-band

Using QGIS's *Merge* and *Rearrange raster tools*, I have created a 5-band raster based on:

- A RGB raster with an alpha band,
- A single-band NIR raster.

The original RGB raster's bands are all automatically detected and interpreted by QGIS (screenshot). I want to reproduce this for my new raster.

[image: Symbology menu for the original RGB raster. Each band is labaled with a color interpretation.]

Using the *Raster information...* tool ([as suggested here](https://geomwales.org/renaming-raster-bands/)), I can see a `ColorInterp` parameter in the generated html file. However, I cannot find a matching parameter in the xml file.

[image: Side by side view of the html raster information (left) and xml file (right).]

Here is a transcription of the metadata:

```
<PAMDataset>
  <PAMRasterBand band="1">
    <UnitType>metre</UnitType>
    <Metadata>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">255</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">137.68055874329</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">5</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">78.204976720939</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT">100</MDI>
    </Metadata>
  </PAMRasterBand>
  <PAMRasterBand band="2">
    <UnitType>metre</UnitType>
    <Metadata>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">255</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">146.04449533328</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">16</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">72.316293490795</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT">100</MDI>
    </Metadata>
  </PAMRasterBand>
  <PAMRasterBand band="3">
    <UnitType>metre</UnitType>
    <Metadata>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">255</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">110.86670480457</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">0</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">93.577575298367</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT">100</MDI>
    </Metadata>
  </PAMRasterBand>
  <PAMRasterBand band="4">
    <UnitType>metre</UnitType>
    <Metadata>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">255</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">181.04600155079</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">0</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">115.71117369521</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT">100</MDI>
    </Metadata>
  </PAMRasterBand>
</PAMDataset>
```

I am using QGIS 3.10 to read and display the raster.

How can I coerce QGIS to default to the proper color interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, creating a .qml style file as described in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J94YRpzZNVQ). This is good enough for me to move forward with my project.

However, if anyone could still shed light on what is happening with the original file (where/how the ColorInterpret information is stored), I would be happy to read about it.

Answer (score 0):

Old mate in [How do you label bands in a GDAL VRT so that their label is recognised in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428677/how-do-you-label-bands-in-a-gdal-vrt-so-that-their-label-is-recognised-in-qgis) encountered a similar problem

From his problem I found that manually inserting `<ColorInterp>` into a .vrt did the trick, I wonder if it works the same for your .xml

[image: Insert colour interp]